# Python thread fails to time out when terminal command requires user input

Tags: python, multithreading, latex, python-multiprocessing, xelatex

### The Task

I'm building a **Python** script, the purpose of which is to audit a number of **.tex** files, and  one step in this auditing process is to test **whether each file will compile**, each file being compiled using the terminal command `xelatex filename.tex`.

These are the methods with which I'm testing whether a given file compiles:

```py
def run_xelatex(self):
    """ Ronseal. """
    self.latex_process = Popen(["xelatex", "current.tex"], stdout=PIPE)
    lines = self.latex_process.stdout.readlines()
    for line in self.latex_process.stdout:
        self.screentext = self.screentext+line.decode("utf-8")+"\n"

def attempt_to_compile(self):
    """ Attempt to compile an article, and kill the process if
    necessary. """
    thread = Thread(target=self.run_xelatex())
    thread.start()
    thread.join(3)
    if thread.is_alive():
        self.latex_process.kill()
        thread.join()
        return False
    return True
```

In English: I create a thread, which in turn creates a process, which in turn tries to compile a given file. If the thread times out, then that file is marked as being uncompilable.

### The Problem

The problem is that, if `xelatex` finds some bad syntax, it asks the user for manual input in order to resolve the issue. But then, for some reason, **the thread does not time out when the process is waiting for user input**. This means that, when I try to run the script, it stops in mid-flow at several points, until I mash the return key to get things going again. This is not ideal.

### What I Want

- An explanation of why a thread fails to time out when a process within it asks for user input.
- A solution to the problem, either by forcing the thread to time out in the above circumstances, or by preventing xelatex from asking for user input.
- Alternatively, an explanation for why what I'm trying to achieve is totally insane, and a suggestion for a better line of attack.

Comment: `-interaction=nonstopmode`?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thanks! Now if I could just work out why the thread wouldn't time out in the first place, my joy would be complete.

Comment: Why should it time out?

Comment: In my head: the code in `attempt_to_compile` gives the compilation process three seconds (`thread.join(3)`) and then, if it's still alive, kills the process (`self.latex_process.kill()`) and moves on. Have I massively misunderstood how threading works? That's entirely possible.